# Script Gsetting not working in cron job

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, cron

i wrote a script to change automatically the theme of my pc. The script works without any problem in terminal, but when i put it  in cron, i get this error

```
dconf-WARNING **: 02:52:01.932: failed to commit changes to dconf: Conncetion closed
```

How can i fix this? i spent hours googling but nothing.

This is my script:

```
AutoThemeSwithcer.sh 
#!/bin/bash 

CurrenTime="$(date +%H)"
NIGHT_TIME=7
DAY_TIME=8
DAY_THEME="Sierra-light"
NIGHT_THEME="Sierra-dark"
USER=robin994

NIGHT_IMAGE_PATH="/home/$USER/Immagini/mojave-night.jpg"
DAY_IMAGE_PATH="/home/$USER/Immagini/mojave-day.jpg"

CT=$(( 10#$CurrenTime-12 ))

if [ $CT -ge 0 ] 
    then
    if [ $CT -ge $NIGHT_TIME ] 
        then 
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$NIGHT_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$NIGHT_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "$NIGHT_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$NIGHT_IMAGE_PATH"

        else
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$DAY_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$DAY_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "$DAY_THEME"
             gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$DAY_IMAGE_PATH"

    fi

elif [ $(( $CT + 12 )) -ge $DAY_TIME ] 
    then 
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$DAY_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$DAY_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "$DAY_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$DAY_IMAGE_PATH"
    else
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$NIGHT_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$NIGHT_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "$NIGHT_THEME"
         gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$NIGHT_IMAGE_PATH"
fi
```

this is my cron file:

```
Cron
#Borrowed from anacron
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/robin99$
#End borrowed from anacron


DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORITY=/home/robin994/.Xauthority
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-qQv0mtFe42,guid=f0a53dfd4343da$
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=14893

* * * * * bash -x AutoThemeSwitcher.sh > /home/robin994/bin/auto3.log 2$
```

```
Log file

++ date +%H
+ CurrenTime=02
+ NIGHT_TIME=7
+ DAY_TIME=8
+ DAY_THEME=Sierra-light
+ NIGHT_THEME=Sierra-dark
+ NIGHT_IMAGE_PATH=/home//Immagini/mojave-night.jpg
+ DAY_IMAGE_PATH=/home//Immagini/mojave-day.jpg
+ CT=-10
+ '[' -10 -ge 0 ']'
+ '[' 2 -ge 8 ']'
+ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Sierra-dark

(process:19539): dconf-WARNING **: 02:52:01.918: failed to commit changes to dconf: La connessione è chiusa
+ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Sierra-dark

(process:19543): dconf-WARNING **: 02:52:01.923: failed to commit changes to dconf: La connessione è chiusa
+ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name Sierra-dark

(process:19547): dconf-WARNING **: 02:52:01.927: failed to commit changes to dconf: La connessione è chiusa
+ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home//Immagini/mojave-night.jpg

(process:19551): dconf-WARNING **: 02:52:01.932: failed to commit changes to dconf: La connessione è chiusa
```

Comment: In general, stuff that is meant for each user's GUI  is difficult to make work from  cron. Just turn it into a script that runs persistently via `while` loop, and add it to Startup Applications list so that when you log into GUI the script starts automatically.

Comment: yea i noticed that.... anyway i used your approach and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for the hint :)